# Entity Framework and Repository Pattern

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern

I am trying to use the Repository pattern with EF4 and I am just not sure how to make Lazy Loading work with it. If I return an object, say a Customer, and I want to be able to get at it's Orders, maybe, not for sure, how should I go about this?

How long should I let the Context live for? Should I just go back and get the collection of Orders?

Any examples would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

**Edit**

So if I have a Repository like so (assuming I have POCO classes for Category and SubCategory):

```
Public Class CategoryRepository
    Implements ICategoryRepository

    Public Function GetCategories() As List(Of Category)
        Using db As New DBContext <-- Entity Framework Context
            return db.Categories.ToList()
        End Using
    End Function

End Class
```

And then consume it like this in the Controller:

```
Public Function Index() As ActionResult
    Dim m As New CategoryViewModel
    m.Categories = _Repository.GetCategories()

    Return View(m)
End Function
```

If I try in the View to say:

```
Category.SubCategories.Count
```

It blows up saying the ObjectContext is disposed.

Comment: The lazy loading does this out of the box if you have a foreign key on your Orders refering back to your primary key on Customer. Also, I would let the context handle itself or are you thinking of introducing caching?

Comment: @Carnotaurus - See my edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're following the concept that Repositories exist once per aggregate, then you'll (likely) load the tree the way you'll know you will use it, in the repository.  So for your example, you'd call db.Categories.Include("SubCategories") to eager-load them.  You might also have different methods like "GetCategoriesDeep()" and "GetCategoriesShallow()" to differentiate if you have different scenarios.

To answer your deeper question, the context should last for a single transaction (however you define that in your app).   In your case, like I say above, it seems like the correct boundary for it is the repository's method call.  The controller should decide whether the user is requesting a collection w/ or w/o subcategories, and then call the right method on the repo to answer that question. T he view shouldn't have to have access to the data context (even indirectly via lazy loading).

Comment: So a Repository could potentially have many methods on it? Also, how come M$ shows articles like this: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments). This is misleading in that they are letting the context live through the life of the repository and never disposing?

Comment: So are you saying you should load the whole graph for the aggregate? So for example, on a customer page, you would load them, their addresses, their order history, etc all in one shot? So really in this pattern there is no lazy loading, and it breaks the whole de-coupling anyways?

Comment: Not always. My point was that when you're kicking out a view that needs it, your code feeding the view should know that.  The view should be provided everything it needs, preloaded.  The pattern itself is subject to a lot of debate, so some folks will favor fewer methods, treating it just like a in-memory collection. Others (like me) think that the realities of development often call for other methods than just the basics.